# Sending WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST to some applications hangs them

Tags: qt, winapi, input-language

I am writing custom keyboard switcher and found, that some applications hang with it. First I thought, that there is an endless loop in my app or something like this, but the found, that even sending a message with 3rd party tool can hang the app.

[image]

Examples of the apps hanging are Comsol Multyphysics 5.3a and Pinnacle Studio 20.

I read somewhere, that this can be the problem with Qt, but on my side I don't undestand, how can I detect such applications and control them without hanging?

---

Can it be this issue: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-59889

---

I don't understand, why doesn't application hang if I change language with toolbar widget? According to documentation, it does the same: posts WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST message!

---

I have captured messages with Spy++ and saw the default switcher doesn't send this message, it sends only

[image]

I don't understand, how application knows which language to choose if `WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE` it sends itself.

Comment: If you are using `SendMessage()`, try using `SendMessageTimeout()` instead

Comment: For this message `PostMessage` should be used (and from screenshoot it looks OP tried `PostMessage`). If you suspect Qt based applications, maybe create simple sample in Qt and debug it. Or find open scorce application with this problem.

Comment: The only reference to `WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST` in Qt source tree is in `qcoreapplication_win.cpp` and it is used only to translate it's code to meaningfull string name. `WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE` is processed in `qapplication_win.cpp`. Check it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I am using post message

Comment: This link [waitforsingleobject-why-you-should-never-use-it](https://marc.durdin.net/2012/08/waitforsingleobject-why-you-should-never-use-it/) form your link could explain it (`KLF_SETFORPROCESS`).

Comment: @DanielSęk ya, but what can I do from my side?

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem
The reason is that qt has a bug in processing WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST

```
# 重写窗口消息处理
def wndProc(self, hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam):
    if msg == 80:
        logger.info("msg={},wParam={},lParam={}".format(msg, wParam, lParam))
        # 如果是英文输入法
        if lParam == 67699721:
            # 手动调api切换英文输入法
            intptr = LoadKeyboardLayout("0409", 1)
            ActivateKeyboardLayout(intptr, KLF_ACTIVATE)
            # 禁止向下传递消息
            return False
        # sougou
        # if lParam == 134481924:
        #     return False
    return CallWindowProc(
        self.oldWndProc,
        hWnd,
        msg,
        wParam,
        lParam
    )
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).